# How to Upload a File within HTML Context

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I'm trying to get a basic PHP script up and running where a user uploads a file to the server, and the file is saved to a folder on the server. I am using a HTML form that looks like

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" size="50000000" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

and I have a PHP file saved as upload_file.php that looks like

```
<?php
$target = "upload/";
$target = $target . basename($_FILES['uploaded']['name']);
$ok     = 1;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . "
has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

The issue is that after the file is uploaded, it simply shows the php code. Nothing else occurs, and no image is saved in uploads. I've looked at several tutorials, and none of them seem to mention this. I'm guessing it's glaringly obvious, but I could use some help. The error `echo "Sorry...` never occurs either.

Thanks.

Quick Note: I'm using Apache to host a local web server.

Comment: You should install PHP and configure Apache to process php files. http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

Comment: and if you try to run a simple "Hello World" php script does it work or does it show its source code?

Comment: change `$_FILES['uploaded']` and `$_FILES['uploadedfile']` to `$_FILES['file']` and try, since your input name is `file` in the html.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing it's as Phantom and Alexandre T said. I neglected to install PHP on Apache, so thanks for the heads up. I just downloaded and (hopefully) installed it now, so I'm gonna try again. I followed the instructions given by Phantom, but the version of PHP I used had a slightly different `.dll` file (ended with _4 as opposed to _2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it simply shows the php code, then PHP is not running. Verify tha PHP is installed and mod_php5 activated.

http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/install-php-5-apache-windows.shtml

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be it. Now I'm just getting the error code given by `echo`, which is better than I was. Thanks for the help.